# cordova geolocation plugin doesnt work

Tags: cordova, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use the plugin cordova-plugin-geolocation, but does not work, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: geolocationSuccess is not defined
```

I have the plugin and permissions in the manifest correctly, simply does not work. If anyone knows the solution, I thank you for the help.

Android manifiest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
```

Javascript

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                         [geolocationError],
                                         [geolocationOptions]);

var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
         ');
};
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer as it doesn't contain any code. You'll need to post your code so that people can look at it and point out where the problem is. It's preferred that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                     [geolocationError],
                                     [geolocationOptions]);
```

to

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess,
onError,
{
    maximumAge: 3000,
    timeout: 5000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
}
);
```